# Text recommendations for linear algebra (tensors, jordan forms)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, book-recommendation, jordan-normal-form

I'm having extreme difficulty trying to understand to topic of tensor products, freespaces, and jordan forms.

Are there any text books that take an elementary approach to these topics that you may recommend?

I am currently using advanced linear algebra by roman, but other sources would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Peter Lax's book is usually highly recommended for Linear Algebra. I believe it covers Jordan Forms and Tensor Products, but only does so in the appendices.

For tensors, any good book on general relativity would serve you well (Das, Schutz, to name a few). However, you can also check a [Quick introduction to tensor analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403252) which is self contained and quite good.

I've heard very good things about Matrix Analysis by Horn, which seems to cover Jordan forms in depth.

I'm sorry to say I don't have anything for free spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll look into them.

Comment: Nice reference! +1